# Example of a progressively measurable process not optional

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples, filtrations

Let $X$ be a stochastic process on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_{t}\}_{t\geq 0},\mathbb{P})$ with value in $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Borel sigma algebra and the Lebesgue measure. We know that each of the following properties implies the next (definitions reported at the end of the section)

1. Predictable
2. Optional
3. Progressively measurable
4. Adapted and measurable
5. Adapted

I have found a simple example of a process that is optional but not predictable (see the end of this post) so that the inclusion $1\subset 2$ is evident and of a process that is adapted but not measurable (see the end of this post) so that the inclusion $4\subset 5$ is evident.

To complete the picture I need an example, which is not obvious to me, of a process that is progressively measurable but not optional. Any ideas?

**Example of a process optional but not predictable**.
The process
$$
X_t = \begin{cases}
0 & 0\leq t<1\\
\xi & t\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
where $\xi$ is, for example, a binary random variable $\mathbb{P}[\xi=\pm 1]=p\in(0,1)$. If we consider the filtration $\{F_t^{X}\}_{t\geq 0}$ generated by $X$ we have that any $F_t^{X}$-adapted process must be constant in $[0,1)$ because $F_t^X=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ for $0\leq t<1$. If the process is, in addition, also left-continuous, it must be constant in $[0,1]$. Accordingly, any predictable process must be constant in $[0,1]$ and so $X$ is not predictable, but it is optional because it is (trivially) $F_t^X$-adapted and right-continuous with left-limit.

**Example of a process adapted but not measurable**.
It is enough to consider a non-measurable Borel set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and the constant (in $\omega$) process $X_t(\omega)=\mathbb{1}_{A}(t)$. The process is adapted to any filtration (being constant) but trivially it is not measurable:
$$
\{(s,\omega)\in [0,\infty)\times\Omega| X_{s}(\omega)=1\}= A\times\Omega\notin\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal{F},
$$

**DEFINITIONS**

Consider the product space $\Omega\times[0,\infty)$ equipped with the product sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))$. A measurable stochastic process is any application
$$
X:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
$$
measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))/\mathcal{B}([-\infty,\infty])$. The predictable sigma-algebra $\mathcal{P}$ is the sigma-algebra on $\Omega\times[0,\infty)$ generated by all the left-continuous and adapted processes. The optional sigma-algebra $\mathcal{O}$ is the sigma-algebra on $\Omega\times[0,\infty)$  generated by all the right-continuous and adapted processes.
A process is said to be **predictable** if it is $\mathcal{P}$-measurable and **optional** if it is $\mathcal{O}$-measurable.
A process is said **progressively measurable** if, for all $t$, it is measurable with respect to the product sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}_t\otimes\mathcal{B}([0,t])$.
Finally, it is **adapted** if, for each $t$, the random variable $X_t(\omega):\Omega\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.

Comment: I know this could be tedious, but it would be better if you included your definitions of those properties of a continuous-time stochastic process, so that the community wouldn't have to deal with reference issues

Comment: @Snoop sorry, I didn't understand your comment: to which properties do you exactly refer?

Comment: Definitions you are working with of properties 1 to 5

Comment: @Snoop ok, I've added some of the main definitions in their most common forms.

Comment: See Example 2.13 in *An essay on the general theory of
stochastic processes* (Nikeghbali 2005).

Comment: @Math1000 thank you very interesting, it does not give any intuition though, but for sure it is a starting point.